# Implicit conversion in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why are the following results different using JavaScript?

```
console.log(1 + + "2"); // => 3
console.log(1 + "2"); // => 12
```

Is there an implicit conversion in JavaScript?

Comment: `+"2"` converts the string to float so in the first log you are doing `number + float = number` while the second `number + string = string`

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz that's `number + number`, there's no other types in JS other that Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the unary `+` operator on a string, it converts it to a number but this was done explicitly as you appended `+` to a string. That explains why you have `1 + +"2"` being 3.
For the other case you are simply doing string concatenation.

JavaScript has the concept of automatic type conversion which is done implicitly when you perform some operation.

And to answer your question:

> Yes, there is implicit conversion in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No, the *unary plus operator* (the second `+`) explicitely converts a string to a number.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
console.log(Number(1) + Number(+"2"));
console.log(Number(1) + Number("2"));
```

More info about type casting or conversion at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Answer (score 0):

**The `+` operator always explicitly converts `number` into `string` if operating together with `string`**

Basic representation:

- N+S >> N
- S+N >> S
- S+S >> S
- N+N >> N

```
console.log("1"+1) // 11
console.log(1+"1") // 11
console.log(1+1) // 2
console.log("1"+"2") // 12
```

**The `-` operator always explicitly converts `string` into `number` if operating together with `number`**

```
console.log("1"-1) // 0
console.log(1-1) // 0
console.log("1"-"1") // 0
console.log(1-"1") // 0
```

**Unary `+`/`-` operators always explicitly convert `string` into `number`**

```
console.log(11+ +"1") //12
console.log(11+ -"1") //10
```