# "0123"-0 instead of parseInt to Quickly Convert Strings to Numbers in JS

Tags: javascript, math, casting, numbers, parseint

I realized I can convert my number strings back to numbers by simply -0. I was wondering if theres any reason anyone knows of that I shouldn't do this? I think there's a difference in JS between 0 and -0? Any examples of what the purpose/usage of that would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

"100"-0 + 29 = 129;
"100"+ 29 = "10029";

Comment: That is just an [implizit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217891/implicit-conversion-in-javascript) like `+"0123"` would be explizit.  However, be aware of constructs like `"0x123"-0` and `"06e20"-0`.

Comment: Be careful in case you can have `null` instead of a string, this would return `0`.